# Specifying startup commands with socat

Tags: linux, networking, socat

I'm connecting to a simple server which is offering a basic text-based interface using socat like this

```
socat readline TCP4:localhost:8090
```

There are some initial commands I have to execute every time I connect, and I would like to automate this. Is there some way to have socat execute these automatically before going back to readline-mode? Or is there some other program better suited to this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script can be written:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec {fd}<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8090
echo "command" >&$fd
echo "other command" >&$fd
exec socat readline fd:$fd
```